# How do I get shipping information (address, city, etc..) on paypal IPN handler using .net vb

Tags: vb.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

How do you get the shipping information on your ipn Handler page? I have set the no_shipping variable = 2 so when I check out it prompts me for the shipping address. I just need to know what the variable names are so I can Request("") them.

Comment: The variable names are on the site if you did a quick search [**IPN Variables**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/). I will tell you that `vb` will not work for what you want to do, you need to use `asp.net`, `php` etc to do this as the response from `Paypal` can be anytime and would need to hit a server (active address).

Comment: I have looked at these variables before. Could you please point out which variables you are talking about that contain the shipping address? When I said .net vb I mean asp .net vb. I am sorta new to that so I thought it was either asp .net vb or asp .net C#

Comment: Have a look here [Buyer Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) When you get there, you will see many that will get you what you need.

Comment: Ahhh ok. So the thing that no one has ever clarified (and I probably should have tester more) is that when you click to enter a shipping address you can query the same information as if no_shipping = 1. So when you Request("address_street") and no_shipping = 1 then you get the billing address. When you Request("address_street")  when no_shipping = 2, and someone enters a different address for shipping than billing then you get the shipping information. So the answer is you just query the information as you normally would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have no_shipping = 2(it will prompt you for shipping address) and you unclick "Same as billing address" then you can enter the Shipping address. If you enter any of the required fields for shipping then all of the requests dealing with address that you make on the IPN handler (address_street,address_zip,address_city) will only refer to the shipping information. All of the billing information is ignored.